# Capacitor quenching circuit across Brush and Commutator of DC motor

Tags: capacitor, filter, dc-motor, spark

To reduce the spark between brush and commutator segment there is capacitor and resistor spark quenching circuit is placed between each commutator segments.
please find below images for detail idea

**please help me about mathematical equations involved behind this to get idea how exactly spark reduces(damping oscillation concept  and  how it is applicable to below circuit) and how to determine resistance and capacitance values..?**

i am from mechanical engineering background & done some priliminary studies but wants to know details phenomena about this 
thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this actually on a DC machine? What size motor? I've worked with DC motors for 30 years, from lab motors through to 2500HP motors, and never once seen a built in arc suppressor on the commutator.  If a commutator is arcing (different from sparking), it is usually because the brush rigging is out of proper alignment.

Answer (score 4):

The device you have drawn is called an [RC snubber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snubber#RC_snubbers). Since you have a mechanical engineering background, I'll explain it as a mechanical analogy.

If there was some current in the inductor, and then the switch opens, the current must keep flowing. An inductor is like a flywheel: as a flywheel's speed can not change instantaneously (as that would require infinite force), and the current through an inductor can not change instantaneously (as that would require infinite voltage).

So to avoid very high voltages (which usually result in undesirable arcing, melting semiconductors, etc), we must *gently*, not abruptly decrease the current. The capacitor provides a path for that to happen.

The capacitor and resistor across the switch are like a spring and some friction. If you connect a spinning flywheel to a torsion spring, you end up with an oscillation between kinetic energy in the flywheel and elastic potential energy in the spring. Friction dampens the oscillation, producing heat.

The energy that was stored in the inductor draws a current through the two, and as current passes through the capacitor, the voltage across the capacitor increases, and so the energy that was stored in the inductor is transferred to the capacitor.

Eventually all the inductor's energy has been transferred to the capacitor, and now the voltage built up in the capacitor drives a current (this time in the opposite direction) through the inductor. This process repeats, and so the energy oscillates between the capacitor and inductor.

This would continue forever, but the resistor adds a loss of energy to heat, and so the oscillation is damped.

The resistor, capacitor, and inductor make a [series RLC circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RLC_circuit#Series_RLC_circuit), and you can read more about the math there. If you are familiar with any kind of damped mechanical oscillation, you'll see it's essentially the same differential equations.

Comment: Thanks very much sir..iwants to implement this circuit between brush in DC motor commutation segments as shown above figure..

Comment: Thanks very much sir..i wants to implement this circuit between brush in DC motor commutation segments as shown above figure..how to select capacitor and resistance value for this circuit with respect to motor specifications..???how do i need to move further to solve this problem..?thanks

Comment: @ketanpatil I'd suggest you begin by reading the links in the answer, and then asking more specific questions if you get stuck on particular points.

Comment: hello sir I have gone through the articles that  you mention just some queries.as snubber resistance is Rs=(V/I)..in this relation how should determine the value of I and V between two commutator segments..?? Because I is the switching current here &how it differs from current through motor with respect to resistance of coil(Imotor=voltage applied/resistance of motor)..?

Comment: @ketanpatil http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 0):

What you've shown in your drawing is called a "snubber", and there's a plethora of design data available [online](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=snubber%20design).

Comment: Thanks sir please can you help me how to select resistance and capacitance for snubber with DC motor..? i want to mount it between commutation segments as shown in above figure.....thnks